# Getting my head round installing plugins from the command line

Tags: plugins, composer

My command line skills are limited but I’m trying to be better. I’ve been using `composer` successfully for a while to initiate Craft installs, but then subsequently using the Craft web GUI to install plugins.

Today I thought I’d try and use the command line on a fresh local install, which has DB connection details stored in `.env` as is usual. The host is configured through MAMP Pro on Mac OS Mojave.

I’ve run `composer update` on my install and it reported there was nothing to update.

I then used the web GUI to install `craftcms/contact-form` and all went fine, so there is no doubt that my local DB credentials are correct.

Then, in the command line I invoked:

```
composer require craftcms/contact-form-honeypot
```

…which ran fine. And then:

```
./craft install/plugin contact-form-honeypot
```

…and got:

> "failed to install contact-form-honeypot: Craft CMS can’t connect to the database with the credentials in config/db.php."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Incidentally—and this is probably not the issue you were encountering—the handle you pass to `./craft` often differs from the handle passed to `composer`.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a MAMP/local dev issue -- run via the CLI, Craft can't connect to the db. Probably it's looking for the wrong `mysql`.

Check out the [MAMP with Composer and MySQL on the Command Line](https://craftcms.com/guides/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line) article for details.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the instructions through to and including https://craftcms.com/guides/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line#using-mAMPs-mySQL-server-in-terminal, but no joy. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't use MAMP, sorry

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer - here are a couple more links for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRA2k6FICsY is a video that explains the issue in depth, and here's a related Craft module: https://packagist.org/packages/samhernandez/craft-db-paths

Comment: Thanks Sam. That is super helpful in lots of ways. Very well explained :)